# How to copy given figure and rotate it as figure.

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newcent} 
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,3)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=.5]{
\psarcn(3,0){3}{180}{90}
\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
\psarc(1,2){1}{-90}{0}
\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
  }
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,opacity=.5]{
\psarc(0,3){3}{-90}{0}
\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
\psarcn(2,1){1}{180}{90}
\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
\closepath
 }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It produce:

[image]

How to create as the following:

[image]

In PStricks, is there a command to copy given figure? OR I have to draw 4 figures ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\myFig{%
  \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=.5]{%
    \psarcn(3,0){3}{180}{90}\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
    \psarc(1,2){1}{-90}{0}\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
  }%
  \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,opacity=.5]{%
    \psarc(0,3){3}{-90}{0}\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-90}
    \psarcn(2,1){1}{180}{90}\psarc(2,0){2}{90}{180}
    \closepath
  }%
}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(6,6)
\rput(0,3){\myFig}
\rput{-270}(6,3){\myFig}
\rput{180}(6,3){\myFig}
\rput{-90}(0,3){\myFig}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Saving more characters.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1pt]{standalone}
\degrees[4]

\def\a#1{\pscustom[fillcolor=#1]{%
    \psarcn(3,0){3}{2}{1}\psarcn(1,3){2}{0}{-1}\psarc(1,2){1}{-1}{0}\psarc(2,0){2}{1}{2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[fillstyle=solid,opacity=.5](6,6)
\foreach \p/\t in {0/0,0/-1,6/-3,6/2}{\rput{\t}(\p,3){\a{blue}\rput{2}(3,3){\a{yellow}}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]